# CUDA driver version is insufficient for runtime version

Tags: cuda

I am getting this msg (CUDA driver version is insufficient for CUDA runtime version) when running deviceQuery in samples. This has been asked several times, but I could not find what happens on my Mac OSX. I just have installed CUDA7.5 driver+toolkit+sample downloaded from https://developer.nvidia.com/cuda-downloads. I could not find any old version under /Developer/NVIDIA/ directory, nor anything symlinked to /usr/local/cuda/lib except the ones from /Developer/NVIDIA/CUDA-7.5/lib. Not sure if there could be some old driver hiding at other places. Your help is really appreciated. thanks!

Comment: what GPU is in your mac, and what is your Mac OSX version?  Did you carefully follow the instructions in the [mac installation guide for CUDA](http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-installation-guide-mac-os-x/index.html#abstract)?

Comment: Thanks Robert. Looks like my mac graphic card is intel integrated, which does not support CUDA...